# SSH Can't delete file that ls says exists

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, files, docker

I've got a file that I cannot remove via SSH.

If I run an `ls` command on the directory, it clearly exists, but if it try to run an `rm` on the file it says:

```
cannot remove 'database.sql': No such file or directory
```

If I check the permissions on both the file and folder, it is `777`, so I should have access to delete it.

If I run `lsattr`, it tells me:

```
No such file or directory While reading flags on ./database.sql
```

Finally, if I try to run `rm .` it again tells me:

```
rm: cannot remove 'database.sql': No such file or directory
```

Somehow it both knows that file is there (many commands "see" it), and can't remove it.

```
all-in-one-wp-migration/storage/sgmq5lpwyiio>ls -l
total 2327360
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 2383152307 Jun  3 05:56 database.sql

all-in-one-wp-migration/storage/sgmq5lpwyiio>rm database.sql
rm: cannot remove 'database.sql': No such file or directory

all-in-one-wp-migration/storage/sgmq5lpwyiio>lsattr
lsattr: No such file or directory While reading flags on ./database.sql

all-in-one-wp-migration/storage/sgmq5lpwyiio>rm *.*
rm: cannot remove 'database.sql': No such file or directory

all-in-one-wp-migration/storage/sgmq5lpwyiio>
```

Comment: Looks like filesystem corruption. What filesystem is it? What is the result of `file *` in that folder?

Comment: It is a docker container, hosted on Azure. File * results in "database.sql: writable, executable, regular file, no read permission".

Comment: The _no read permission_ might point to the problem (if it's not corruption in whichever filesystem you are using).

Comment: Can you run `fsck` on that volume? What filesystem is it?

Comment: Running fsck returns: fsck from util-linux 2.29.2

Comment: docker stack filesystem, if your file is on a "lower" stack, you might be unable to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the file owner and group is set to "nobody" and "nogroup".  The "nobody" user and "nogroup" user group have the least possible privileges on the system.  But even then you should be able to delete the file.

Do you have write permission to the directory that the file is in?  Deleting a file may require write permissions in the directory as well, since you are removing something from a directory.  Did you try editing the file?  The directory may not have write access for you but, the file may have write access.

It could be file or system corruption as stated in the comments above, or it could be that a service might be running and is using that file.

Try to do `chown` and `chgrp` to make you as the owner, and the owning group to a group that you are in.

Comment: Both commands fail on the file, and while they seem to run change nothing on the group level. My guess is that docker is overriding/undoing the change.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems when there is an unintended unnoticed space or tab character somewhere in the file name that is being printed during a listing done using some sort of wild-card character.  In some shells, if you type a tab after the file name on a command line, it will fill in characters at the end that you might not be seeing.  You might be able to check by using a character count with `wc -c` on the file name, being aware of the unprinted `\n` character that is always counted.

Comment: using wc -c database.sql just returns 0.

Comment: "ls -1d database.sql* | wc -c"  OR something like "ls -1d (ASTERISK)database.sql(ASTERISK) | wc -c " (whatever "ls" command prints only the name of the file of interest)  I tried with * instead of (ASTERISK) and two of them disappear and turn the text between them into italics).

Comment: If filename is "visible.part  " then: ls -1d *| egrep 'visible.part' | egrep '[ ]' should print the file (a space between the [ ]). To explicitly visualize the spaces: ls -1d * | egrep visible.part | egrep '[ ]' | sed -e's/^/=>/g' -e's/$/<=/g'   which should print "=>visible.part  <='     If there are spaces, you can delete by: "rm visible.part(backslash) (backslash) "  if there were 2 spaces.  (backslash is not printing out properly in the text box on this site, also the double space is printing out as a single space on this website)

Comment: @jmf7 if you format your text `as *code* by   using backticks` you can have extra spaces, asterisks, etc.